# Nativescript not detecting swipe event on ScrollView

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, scrollview, nativescript

I'm trying to create an app that has several buttons (each responds to a tap) inside a separate page, each page should be accessed with a swipe. With the following code I get the buttons to respond to taps but the swipe event doesn't fire reliably (it works after I tap on the bottom label)

**page1.xml**

```
<Page actionBarHidden="true" loaded="loaded" xmlns="http://schemas.nativescript.org/tns.xsd">
    <ScrollView orientation="horizontal" swipe="onSwipe">
        <GridLayout width="100%" height="100%" class="gridClass" rows="*, *, *, *, auto" columns="*, *, *, *" row="0" col="0">
            <Image src="~/images/btn1.png" row="0" col="0" tap="onTap" />
            <Image src="~/images/btn2.png" row="0" col="1" tap="onTap" />
            <Image src="~/images/btn3.png" row="0" col="2" tap="onTap" />
            <Image src="~/images/btn4.png" row="0" col="3" tap="onTap" />

            <Image src="~/images/btn5.png" row="1" col="0" tap="onTap" />
            <Image src="~/images/btn6.png" row="1" col="1" tap="onTap" />
            <Image src="~/images/btn7.png" row="1" col="2" tap="onTap" />
            <Image src="~/images/btn8.png" row="1" col="3" tap="onTap" />

            <Image src="~/images/btn9.png" row="2" col="0" tap="onTap" />
            <Image src="~/images/btn10.png" row="2" col="1" tap="onTap" />
            <Image src="~/images/btn11.png" row="2" col="2" tap="onTap" />
            <Image src="~/images/btn12.png" row="2" col="3" tap="onTap" />

            <Image src="~/images/btn13.png" row="3" col="0" tap="onTap" />
            <Image src="~/images/btn14.png" row="3" col="1" tap="onTap" />
            <Image src="~/images/btn15.png" row="3" col="2" tap="onTap" />
            <Image src="~/images/btn16.png" row="3" col="3" tap="onTap" />

            <Label id="banner" text="ad placeholder" row="4" colSpan="4" height="70" backgroundColor="blue" />
        </GridLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</Page>
```

**page1.js**

```
function loaded(args) {
  // do something on page load
}

function playAudio(args) {
    // play some audio
}

function onTap(args) {
   playAudio(args)
}

function onSwipe(args) {
    // transition to next page
}

exports.onTap = onTap;
exports.onSwipe = onSwipe;
exports.loaded = loaded;
```

**Update**

I ended up using the [nativescript-slides](https://github.com/TheOriginalJosh/nativescript-slides) plugin to solve the issue and it works well so far, thank you for the suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see the need for a ScrollView at all here, a GridLayout is meant to take available width and height, so you neither have to set a height. Remove them and try attaching swipe event to GridLayout.

Comment: That's what I originally tried and the GridLayout doesn't respond to swipe gestures until I try to swipe/tap the label at the bottom

Comment: If you can create a playground example where the issue can be reproduced I may able to take a look.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to have swipe gesture without headache is TabView. Yes, it will not be separate pages. If you need to keep things separate you can always place the contents of each Tabs in individual directories and import them as custom components.

Comment: I thought of that but didn't want to display the tab names and I haven't seen any way to completely remove them on iOS

Answer (score 0):

If you are open for using a TabView, [here](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-tsc&id=mPZHXU) is how you can hide the TabBar in iOS.

```
export function onLoaded(args: EventData) {
  const tabView = <TabView>args.object,
   tabBarController = tabView.ios;

  if (tabBarController) {
    setTimeout(() => {
     const frame = tabBarController.tabBar.frame;
     tabBarController.tabBar.frame = CGRectOffset(frame, 0, frame.size.height);
    }, 100);
   }
}
```